# Django signals @receiver POST_SAVE not working on PROD (ok on DEV)

Tags: python, django, signals, production

Getting nuts ...
**On dev**, my signals (for sending an alert by mail) works for all save (create + update) and delete.
But **on prod**, only delete action sends an email. I didn't notice at once delete signals were working so I spent much time looking for an issue caused by firewall (blocked email outgoing).

**Post Save**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Navette)
def alerte(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    ref = instance.ref
    user = instance.user.username

    if created:
        alert(pour=['tintin@gmail.com'],
              sujet=f'Nouvelle navette pour la référence {ref} créé par {user}')
    else:
        alert(pour=['tintin@gmail.com'],
              sujet=f'Mise à jour de la navette pour la référence {ref} par {user}')
```

**Post Delete**

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Navette)
def alerte(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ref = instance.ref
    user = instance.user
    alert(pour=['tintin@gmail.com'],
          sujet=f'La navette pour la référence {ref} a été supprimée par {user}')
```

just for info : alert.py

```
def alert(**kwargs):

    #ref = kwargs.get('ref', 'noref')
    de = kwargs.get('de', 'toto@gmail.com')
    pour = kwargs.get('pour', 'tintin@gmail.com')
    sujet = kwargs.get('sujet', 'Sujet Général')
    contenu = kwargs.get('contenu', 'cf. objet du mail')
    fichier = kwargs.get('fichier', '')

    host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    port = 465
    user = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    passw = settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = sujet
    msg['From'] = de
    msg['To'] = pour
    msg.set_content('HTML uniquement')

    msg.add_alternative(contenu, subtype='html')

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, port) as smtp:
        smtp.login(user, passw)
        smtp.send_message(msg)
```

As said almost everywhere, I declared my app not just with its name in settings.py : `'navette.apps.NavetteConfig',` and registrered the app config in its `__init__` -> `default_app_config = 'navette.apps.ActivityAppConfig'` even if I thought Ik heard it was not necessary anymore on DJANGO 3.

Finally, heres my apps.py for this app

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class NavetteConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'navette'

    def ready(self):
        import navette.signals
```

Any idea ?

**EDIT**

**navette.views**

```
@login_required
def NavetteCreateView(request):
    form = NavetteDetailForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NavetteDetailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            navette_ref = form.cleaned_data.get('ref')
            logr.debug(f'{navette_ref} - enregistrée')
            messages.success(
                request, f'La navette {navette_ref} a bien 
        été créée.')
            return redirect('/navettes')
    else:
        form = NavetteDetailForm()

    context = {'form': form, 'title': 'Nouvelle Navette'}
    return render(request, 'navette/navette_form.html', 
context)
```

I checked the form_valid -> True

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your receiver function is getting garbage-collected.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) say this on the subject:

> Note also that Django stores signal handlers as weak references by
> default, so if your handler is a local function, it may be garbage
> collected. To prevent this, pass weak=False when you call the signal’s
> connect().

Try using `@receiver(post_save, sender=Navette, weak=False)`

Comment: Alas , not better. I (re) read the doc and didn't find any other clue. Thanks @Julien Cortesi

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround but if you are really going nuts over this you can try using the `pre_save` signal instead. With `pre_save` you can check manually whether the instance has an `id`, if it doesn't have it then it's a new object.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Navette)
def alerte(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ref = instance.ref
    user = instance.user.username

    if not instance.id:
        alert(pour=['tintin@gmail.com'],
              sujet=f'Nouvelle navette pour la référence {ref} créé par {user}')
    else:
        alert(pour=['tintin@gmail.com'],
              sujet=f'Mise à jour de la navette pour la référence {ref} par {user}')
```

Comment: not better with pre_save. I tried to add some prints to see where signal breaks but it even doesn't trigger `print('signal triggered')

    if created:
        print('instance created')`
Thanks for your time. I keep digging ...

Comment: maybe a clue : I didn't notice that even in DEV mode (local), the signal doesn't work anymore for object creation with `pre_save`. I added my view in original question. Maybe the origin of my issue

Comment: Don't know if it's related but I added loggers in my functions for seing where the script failed. And without modifying anything else, now I can receive create/update mails. I also noticed that `git push` was not sufficient for applying my code changes in prod. Each time I modify alert/signal, I need to restart apache2. May be its because of this all my code modifications were not taken in account.
This will remain a mystery ...